# "go around in a circle" in context of a game

Tags: meaning, verbs

If instructions to a game are written as "they go around in a circle and [do something]", is it a valid interpretation that they sit (or stand) in a circle, and that the turn goes from player to player in a circle? A friend of mine and I are having a discussion about this, but I can't find any dictionary or such which backs this up. I often see "to go around in a circle" used in this way, though.

Comment: If the instructions  only say "go around in a circle", without any hint as to what composes the "circle", then the instructions are very poorly written.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "they" [metonymically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) for "their turn". Here are a couple of examples in print that use the word this way (emphasis, mine):

- "... we played a version of the game duck, duck, goose, which people would make up any pair of words as **they went around the circle** patting heads: cup, cup, saucer; sun, sun, moon; and so on. One boy, when it was **his turn**, ..."
  [- Representing Youth, edited by Amy L. Best](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=RTfVOuvzoOIC&pg=PA279&dq=%22they%20went%20around%20the%20circle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFkvWCtondAhUEUt4KHaJWBNIQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22they%20went%20around%20the%20circle%22&f=false)
- "This game had the children **sit** in a circle holding onto a parachute and hundreds of small pompoms in the middle. **They went around the circle** allowing each child to say what they wanted to put on the popcorn."
  [- A Description of Movement-based Programs for Preschool Children AGES 3-5, 
  Martha Bratton Robertson](https://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/handle/1903/1532/umi-umd-1518.pdf;sequence=1)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the context, I can only guess. If the game were a card game or a board game and people were sitting around a table playing, I would certainly expect that the instructions are saying that players should take turns, proceeding around the group in a circular fashion.

Of course there are other games where players actually move around in circles. If I remember correctly, Ring Around the Rosie would be such a game. My childhood is a very long time ago now though so I don't remember very well how that was played but I remember children forming a large circle and joining hands with someone in the middle; the circle proceeded to move around the person in the middle.

I also remember a game called telephone where information moved around the circle and everyone stayed stationary but close enough together to whisper. The first person would whisper a phrase to the person on their left and that person would then repeat the phrase - or more commonly paraphrase it - to the person to their left and so forth until it got all the way around the circle. When the message reached the person immediately beside the person who made the original phrase, the person who started the message would state their original message and the last person to hear the message would state what *they* heard. We'd always be duly amused at how the message had changed, sometimes very dramatically and even humourously, by the time it got back to its starting point.